# remoteIO how to play it?

Tags: objective-c

i manage to get the recordCallBck and deal with the buffer data.
now i want to play that data.
i have the play callback but i just cant find anywhere how to **play** this buffers.

callback:

```
static OSStatus playbackCallback(void *inRefCon, 
                          AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags, 
                          const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp, 
                          UInt32 inBusNumber, 
                          UInt32 inNumberFrames, 
                          AudioBufferList *ioData) {

    for (int i = 0 ; i < ioData->mNumberBuffers; i++){      
        AudioBuffer buffer = ioData->mBuffers[i];
        unsigned char *frameBuffer = buffer.mData;
```

now what?
how would i play that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at this example, helped me out a lot when trying to deal with the data. This is an example of a working app that plays anything you have spoken into the microphone. It uses 2 callbacks, one for recording the data and placing in a global audio buffer and a second for getting that data back into the playback callback.

http://www.stefanpopp.de/2011/capture-iphone-microphone/